# Encrypt in SQL and Decrypt in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, encryption

We want to encrypt ssn, account number, routing number, etc. Is it possible to encrypt in SQL (using ENCRYPTBYKEY function) and decrypt in C# or vice-versa? We could encrypt and decrypt using SQL itself but we're using a lot of LINQ queries in our code which we would need to move to SQL. Also, if we encrypt/decrypt in C#, we would not be able to use the encrypted columns in our stored procs and SSRS reports. Please advice the best way to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think its good idea to generate a report that displays entire SSN.

Comment: It smells anti-pattern. Even if you manage to achieve it as is it will probably bite you in the future.

Comment: @sam We won't be showing the entire ssn in the report

Comment: What is the RDBMS platform and version?

Comment: @Igor  SQL Server 2017 v14.0.1000.169

Comment: Not sure if upgrading to 2016 or later is an option. If so there is a feature called [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine) which can manage encryption in the database for you, no need to write special code. You can select which column(s) to encrypt and it can even make use of indexes assuming the client connection provides the correct key / certificate.

Comment: @Ram if SSN is not shown in reports then why do you want to save them in database? You can see my answer below.

Comment: @sam we could get away with ssn but take salary for example. When we download the employee info from the payroll system, we want to encrypt the salary and save it into the database. Now, we need to decrypt the salary to show on the app and on the SSRS report so we can't encrypt and decrypt in SQL or C#.

Answer (score 0):

I will give different answer:

Best practice is, not having decrypt function at all. When user enters data, encrypt/encode them and save them into database. next time, whenever there is need to match users' data, compare encrypted content and allow them to do further operations only if they match.